# App Engine internal appspot service account was deleted. Unable to deploy app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Internal App Engine default service account was deleted. This usually has the appspot.com email address. Unable to undelete the account since the date of deletion is more than 30 days. A new service account was created and assigned with App Engine Admin role. When trying to deploy an app, deployment fails with the following error

Creating App Engine application in project [xxxxxxx] and region [xxxxx]....failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists.

Comment: Try granting the role Editor to the service account. If that does not work, you will need to contact Google Cloud Support.

Comment: I did create a new service account and assigned Editor role. However, I am not sure how to deploy the application in the context of the new service account.

Comment: I was executing the gcloud app deploy from the gcloud console.

Comment: Usually the service account is created when you enable the API. Can you try disabling and enabling the API in your project?

Comment: Usually service accounts are created when you enable a GCP functionality. Enabling API doesn't impact the service account. I created a new project and and enabled App engine and the account was created with the project ID with an appspot .gserviceaccount.com email. Looks like it is somewhere attached to app engine internal config.